# How to judge fast-forward and no-fast-forward in Libgit2?

Tags: merge, pull, libgit2

When I used libgit2 merge, I found that each merge produced a new **oid**, so there should be a function to determine if a merge commit is needed before the merge commit. I use **git_merge_analysis()** to determine which merge method, but it always returns **GIT_MERGE_ANALYSIS_UP_TO_DATE**, wondering if it is a good practice, then what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

git_merge_analysis should return [GIT_MERGE_ANALYSIS_FASTFORWARD](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/HEAD/include/git2/merge.h#L335), when it is possible.  Otherwise, assuming it's not already up to date (commit oids are equal), the normal result indicates a merge is needed as usual - which is when a fast-forward merge isn't possible.

Personally, when first using libgit2, I'd regularly mix-up 'ours' and 'theirs', which led to unexpected results.  As the analysis method is comparing 'theirs' to the current HEAD, you could be getting the up-to-date result if 'theirs' is equal to or already an ancestor of the commit the HEAD currently refers to (which may have been set as a result of a previous merge).  Whereas, if things were swapped around, you'd get the fast-forward result if HEAD was the ancestor of 'theirs'.

Comment: Thank you for your answer sincerely@Kevin